# TensorFlow Recommenders - Queries and Candidate dimensions are not equal

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am buidling a Retrieval Model using TensorFlow Library. When i try to train the model i get this error.
Single query and candidates tensors are in the same shape.

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 256 and 1280000 for '{{node MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=true](MatMul/job_model_15/sequential_75/global_average_pooling1d_70/Mean, args_1)' with input shapes: [?,256], [?,1280000].


        Call arguments received by layer 'streaming_18' (type Streaming):
          • queries=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
          • k=100


    Call arguments received by layer 'retrieval_15' (type Retrieval):
      • query_embeddings=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
      • candidate_embeddings=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
      • sample_weight=None
      • candidate_sampling_probability=None
      • candidate_ids=None
      • compute_metrics=True
      • compute_batch_metrics=True
```

I think fault of this can be in this task:

```
metrics = tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
  candidates=dataset.batch(16).map(freelancer_model)
)

task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(
  metrics=metrics
)
```